AWS lambda: Unable to determine service/operation name to be authorized
I am trying to deploy my lambda based on fastAPI and Mangum and invoke it from API Gateway. If I test it from AWS console from API Gateway, it works and I get reply as it is expected. Then it seems that the integration of Lambda is correct, POST integration is used. Also Lambda is invoked from API gateway, so the permissions should be also correct.
But if I call the endpoint outside AWS I get the error:

Endpoint response body before transformations: <AccessDeniedException>
<Message>Unable to determine service/operation name to be authorized</Message>
</AccessDeniedException>

Do you have any idea where the error is?
Permissions:
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "apigw" {
      statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromApiGateway"
      action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
      function_name = "${aws_lambda_function.api_lambda.function_name}"
      principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      source_arn = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.gapi.execution_arn}/*/*"
}

integrations:
    resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "gapi" {
      rest_api_id             = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.gapi.id}"
      resource_id             = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.gapi.root_resource_id}"
      http_method             = "${aws_api_gateway_method.gapi.http_method}"
      type                    = "AWS_PROXY"
      integration_http_method = "POST"
      uri                     = "${aws_lambda_function.api_lambda.invoke_arn}"
    }

Thank you
I tried to test lambda itself and integration from API gateway from AWS console and both works

The same issue!
